# Java swing with ROS

Tags: java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I wan't to ask if there is anyway to connect Java swing with ROS?

For example, When I click on a button, a launch command should be fired.

I used the following code and it works:

```
try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when I tried ROS command it shows the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "roscore": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at javaapplication2.JFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(JFrame.java:67)
    at javaapplication2.JFrame.access$000(JFrame.java:15)
    at javaapplication2.JFrame$1.actionPerformed(JFrame.java:40)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
```

UPDATE:
`bash -c roscore` produce no errors but nothing works. Because after that I opened a terminal and execute `rosrun` command and it says: `Unable to communicate with master`, meaning that roscoe doesn't work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207030/java-swing-with-ros/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`no such file or directory` usually indicates that you don't have your PATH environment variable set up correctly.

Have you sourced your ROS setup.sh or setup.bash before you run your Java application?

**EDIT**

The setup.bash script does not take arguments; running `setup.bash roscore` is incorrect.

Assuming you have your default bashrc set up to source the ROS setup.bash, running `bash -c roscore` should result in a running roscore. The [docs for Runtime.exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) say that it executes the command in a separate process; are you sure it isn't doing anything?

**EDIT2**

Does your .bashrc source your ROS setup.bash?

You should probably also be checking the process state for the process you spawn, to make sure that it is running, you should check the error output to see if there's anything useful there, and you should check the return code when the process is done, to see if it returned with an error.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0